# Textfield loses focus when user clicks on checkbox (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, textfield

So I'm using a JPasswordField to get the user input, and then give instantaneous feedback regarding the strength of the entered password. My problem is that if the user clicks on the 'hide' checkbox, the string in the textfield isn't immediately masked by '●', but works only when the textfield regains focus. I've tried to use component.getFocus within the mouseListener, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's what this particular listener looks like:

```
inputT.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent hideClicked){
            if (hideC.isSelected()){
                inputT.setEchoChar('•');
                inputT.requestFocus();
            }
            if (!hideC.isSelected()){
                inputT.setEchoChar('\u0000');
                inputT.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: How are you hiding your text? Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, as you can see from the code above, if the checkBox hideC is selected, the string in the passwordField inputT gets masked by '•'. If not, the no masking takes place, and the string is displayed as it is.

Comment: I'm sorry, but just realized that there was an error on my side. Instead of adding a mouseListener to the checkbox, I added it to the input textfield. The requestFocos method works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Show the feedback to the user in a different field than the password field that they are typing into.  Ideally a separate read only component that is to the right of the password in your GUI.  Your password strength feedback would then be updated by a listener on the password field, but the `JPasswordField` could then just work like normal.

Comment: I'm sorry, but just realized that there was an error on my side. Instead of adding a mouseListener to the checkbox, I added it to the input textfield. The requestFocos method works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Start by attaching a `ActionListener` to the the checkbox, this means that user can click or press the space bar to activate the check box

In the `actionPerformed` method, check the state of the checkbox and the required changes.

Use `JPasswordField#selectAll` or `JPassword#requestFocusInWindow` (usually I do it the other way round ;)). If these do not work, you might even consider using `JPassword#repaint` to force the field to repaint

Comment: `setEchoChar(char)` itself call `repaint()` and `revalidate()` inside.

Comment: I'm sorry, but just realized that there was an error on my side. Instead of adding a mouseListener to the checkbox, I added it to the input textfield. The requestFocos method works perfectly fine.

Comment: @sage this is what I would have expected, but given the fact that it did seem to be working, *considering* the use of repaint would ensure that the component is being updated.

Comment: @EnTHuSiAsTx94 You should still consider using an ActionListener

Comment: @MadProgrammer, though i am more interested in `ItemListener` as it is something to do with selection state ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus%28%29

public void requestFocus()

Requests that this Component gets the input focus. Refer to Component.requestFocus() for a complete description of this method.

Note that the use of this method is discouraged because its behavior is platform dependent. Instead we recommend the use of requestFocusInWindow(). If you would like more information on focus, see How to Use the Focus Subsystem, a section in The Java Tutorial.

Also, as MadProgrammer pointed out - your listener is on the JPasswordField instead of the JCheckBox.

Comment: I'm sorry, but just realized that there was an error on my side. Instead of adding a mouseListener to the checkbox, I added it to the input textfield. The requestFocos method works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use mouse listener. For doing on selection, use `ItemListener`:

  ```
  checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

      @Override
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
          if(evt.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
             jPasswordField1.setEchoChar((char)0);
         else jPasswordField1.setEchoChar('*');
      }
  });
  ```

Well, the above code works perfectly for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, but just realized that there was an error on my side. Instead of adding a mouseListener to the checkbox, I added it to the input textfield. The requestFocos method works perfectly fine.

Comment: @EnTHuSiAsTx94, yes i got that and still don't use `MouseListener` for doing things on `CheckBox` selection purpose. As i have shown in the answer use `ItemListener` instead